# Android: Change variable value in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

My application logic is, saving some data in local and send them periodically to the server by `BroadcastReceiver`.

And also I'm having one more feature as send data by manually by a button.

Here the problem is if I sync data manually and also Auto sync happening in the back end and I'm getting duplicate values.

So give me some solution.

Now what I'm doing means
Making one **boolean** value as `true` in `BroadcastReceiver(SyncAlarmReceiver.java)`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    isAutoSync = true; }`
```

and in Manualsync Activity

```
if (!SyncAlarmReceiver.isAutoSync) {
    // then send data to server
}
```

**But the boolean value is not getting change.**

Please give me some solution.

Comment: try to push your `isAutoSync` feature inside your `Preference`. That way you can maintain consistency on your `isAutoSync`variable.

Comment: please give me some simple tutorial to use Preference.. bcz im new to tat